# Highlight a column in excel chart from a dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a sheet with site name and associated values.

```
Site1 100
Site2 123  
Site3 432   
...  
Site20 234
```

and this is represented in a column/bar chart.

there is a dropdown list of the site names. when the user selects a site, I want the associated row/column in the chart is highlighted... (change colour)

is that possible?

Comment: Take a look at [This article](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/11/11/highlight-data-points-scatter-line-charts/) at Chandoo.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to do this is with two helper columns and a stacked column (or bar) chart.

You need a data table where the selected site is plotted in a different series. The series to be highlighted is selected in cell G1.

In the example below, the original data values are in column B. The formula in C2 is

```
=IF(A2<>$G$1,B2,0)
```

The formula in D2 is

```
=IF(A2<>$G$1,0,B2)
```

Copy both formulas down to row 21. Then build a stacked column chart with two series from columns C and D and x axis labels from column A.

[image]